# Why do I get errors when using > > in bash?

Tags: bash

I've been looking up some bash stuff today and a few snippets I've tried have included `> >` which seems to be the cause of the errors I'm receiving.

[Example snippet](https://serverfault.com/questions/59262/bash-print-stderr-in-red-color):

```
command 2> >(while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)
```

Here's what I'm working with.

```
$ bash --help
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin12)
```

**EDIT**
Here are the errors I'm gettting:

```
file.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
file.sh: line 14: `command 2> >(while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is command? And what are you trying to do with the '> >'?

Comment: Right, I know about `>` and `>>`. I don't really understand what `> >` is supposed to do, but I've seen it several times today in my googling, and it's been posted by people with high reputations and people have up-voted the code and whatnot. That specific line is supposed to colorize errors. You can click the [Example snippet](http://serverfault.com/questions/59262/bash-print-stderr-in-red-color) link for more info.

Comment: What errors are you getting? There's nothing wrong with that syntax. `2>` redirects stdout. `>(...)` is substituted with a name for a writable pipe into a subprocess, so it's a lot like `|` but with parentheses.

Comment: By the way, the `>()` syntax is documented here in the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution . IMHO, reading through bashref.html would be a much better use of your time than googling random people's random comments about bash. But YMMV.

Comment: @rici i added the errors. thanks for the link; I'll read up on that.

Comment: are you using `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of file.sh? The first is correct (probably); the second will either run a different shell program or cause `bash` to try to be compatible with `sh`.

Comment: @rici: Re: "`2>` redirects stdout": Huh? Firstly -- it redirects standard *error* (file-descriptor `2`), not standard *output* (file-descriptor `1`). Secondly -- it only does that if it's followed by a file-name to redirect standard-output *to*.

Comment: @ruakh; 1) yes, that was my typo. 2) it is followed by a filename because >() is substituted by a filename (by bash, not by sh)

Comment: @rici: Re: #2: O.K., yes, that's true.

Comment: I'm using almost exactly the same version of bash and don't get an error. When I put it into a script, same thing. What does the rest of your script say? How about the shebang line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674783/978917), Bash 3.2.48 for Mac OS X has some limitations when it comes to process-substitution; it supports it in some cases but not others. Your case is apparently one where it doesn't.

Quoting from the best/most-helpful answer there:

> The one from macports (4.2.37 — normally `/opt/local/bin/bash` if you have it installed) works fine. […] Perhaps you may want to use macports bash for this script.

Comment: It seems to work fine in the version I have, which is `3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)`, almost but not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

The most naive way to solve your problem is the following:

```
while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done < <( { command > /dev/null ; } 2>&1 )
```

We're sending all `stdout` of `command` to `/dev/null` and then then redirecting the `stderr` to `stdin`.

Or the other way round:

```
{ command > /dev/null ; } 2>&1 | while read line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done
```

With these methods you don't have to play too much with file descriptors!

Done.